# 'airflow standalone' code completes but then starts running again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow

I am new to coding and in my process on learning to create data pipeline, I am using aws ec2 instance. I installed python, apache airflow and all the requirements as per the tutorial, but when i run airflow standalone, it successfully creates username and passwrod, but then in some time it starts running the code again. I am unable to connect to airflow using ip4 due to this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeeQv.png)

Please help me find a fix for this. I am not sure if I explained it in  a proper manner, since i am  new to this. Please let me know if you need any further details.